# Powershell Catch Return Value

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, foreach

I have a powershell script that I am trying to add webparts to a sharepoint page automatically. The script below is wrapped in a FOREach-Object and it works fine on the first iteration however on the second itereation it is returning some unwanted information to the powershell screen (and logs I am creating).

I am looking for a way to prevent that from returning anything other than the write-host statements. I originally thought it might be an exception however It looks like the web parts are still being added with no issue and I can't find any reference to an exeption in the return info.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
$addCsv | ForEach-Object{

            $tempwebURL = $_.'SiteURL'
            $pageUrl = $_.'Page'
            $varWebPartZone = $_.'WebPartZone'
            $varChrome = $_.'Chrome'
            $varTitle = $_.'Title'          
            $varPosition = [int]$_.'Position'

            #get current site
            $tempweb= Get-SPWeb -Identity $tempwebURL
            Write-Host ("Adding Web Part to :"+ $tempweb.Title)

            #add webpart
            [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$oxmlReader = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextReader("Path removed");
            $webpartmanager=$tempweb.GetLimitedWebPartManager( $pageUrl,  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)    
            [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart] $oWebPart
            $err = ''
            $oWebPart = new-object $webpartmanager.ImportWebPart($oxmlReader,[ref]$_.Exception.Message)
            $oWebPart.Title = $varTitle
            $oWebPart.ChromeType=$varChrome
            $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($oWebPart, $varWebPartZone, $varPosition)| Out-Null 
            $oWebPart.Dispose() 
            $oxmlReader.Close()
            $webpartmanager.Dispose()
            $tempweb.Dispose()
            $num++

}
```

Below is the information being printed to the screen which I do not want:

```
AllowClose                         : True
AllowConnect                       : True
AllowEdit                          : True
AllowHide                          : True
AllowMinimize                      : True
AllowZoneChange                    : True
AuthorizationFilter                :
CatalogIconImageUrl                :
ChromeState                        : Normal
ChromeType                         : None
ConnectErrorMessage                :
Description                        :
Direction                          : NotSet
DisplayTitle                       : Last Date Modified Explorer
ExportMode                         : None
HasUserData                        : False
HasSharedData                      : False
Height                             :
HelpMode                           : Navigate
HelpUrl                            :
Hidden                             : False
IsClosed                           : False
ImportErrorMessage                 : Cannot import this Web Part.
IsShared                           : True
IsStandalone                       : False
IsStatic                           : False
Subtitle                           :
Title                              : Last Date Modified Explorer
TitleIconImageUrl                  :
TitleUrl                           :
Verbs                              : {}
WebBrowsableObject                 : Removed
Width                              :
Zone                               :
ZoneIndex                          : 0
Controls                           :
BackImageUrl                       :
DefaultButton                      :
GroupingText                       :
HorizontalAlign                    : NotSet
ScrollBars                         : None
Wrap                               : True
AccessKey                          :
Attributes                         : System.Web.UI.AttributeCollection
BackColor                          : Color [Empty]
BorderColor                        : Color [Empty]
BorderWidth                        :
BorderStyle                        : NotSet
ControlStyle                       : System.Web.UI.WebControls.PanelStyle
ControlStyleCreated                : True
CssClass                           :
Style                              : System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection
Enabled                            : True
EnableTheming                      : True
Font                               :
ForeColor                          : Color [Empty]
HasAttributes                      : False
SkinID                             :
TabIndex                           : 0
ToolTip                            :
ClientID                           : g_adea57ed_5d6d_40ee_b468_ce85e37f5e9a
ID                                 : g_adea57ed_5d6d_40ee_b468_ce85e37f5e9a
EnableViewState                    : True
NamingContainer                    :
BindingContainer                   :
Page                               :
TemplateControl                    :
Parent                             :
TemplateSourceDirectory            :
AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory :
Site                               :
Visible                            : True
UniqueID                           : g_adea57ed_5d6d_40ee_b468_ce85e37f5e9a
```

I also welcome any "you could do this better by..." comments. Thanks again.

Comment: For one, you don't need to write `$_.'SiteURL'` – `$_.SiteURL` suffices as well. You only need to use quotes if you have spaces or other significant characters in a property name.

Comment: Remove that line: [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart] $oWebPart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the following line is the culprit:

```
[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart] $oWebPart
```

In the first iteration this won't do much, it's just a cast of `$null`. But in later iterations it retains the value of the previous iteration and outputs it. You don't need that line anyway as it does nothing.

Comment: If you add a `|gm` to the pipeline it would show you what object type is leaking, but I'm reasonably confident that it's the line I pointed out. There are no other lines that might drop something in the pipeline as those are mostly assignments.